# Как правильно использовать Emmet?

Tags: html, emmet

Как мне сразу развернуть сниппет со значением в `src`?

```
script:src[debug.js]+script:src[hide.js]
```

Почему следующая конструкция не развертываеться?

```
button[onclick="hide(this,true); debug('hide button 1');"]{Hide 1}
```

Comment: Не понятно, что именно у тебя не получается? Не плохо было бы узнать в каком редакторе работаешь?  У меня `sublime 3`  и примеры приведенные выше в вопросе работают... О чем вопрос?

Comment: работю в visual studio code

Answer (score 1):

Указанные вами сниппеты работают!

```
script:src[debug.js]+script:src[hide.js]
button[onclick="hide(this,true); debug('hide button 1');"]{Hide 1}
```

Вы можете проверить это в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/df2Les9c).

Возможно, ваш редактор не поддерживает Emmet, либо работает с другой его версией.